# How to display hidden data of one div to another div and when press cross button move it to its real place

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am working on a project where I came across where when I click plus sign the data will hide and the appear in the div next to it. here is the code:
View

```
<fieldset class="col-md-4" >
    <legend>Services</legend>
    <div class="col-md-12" >
    <?php
        $id = 0;
        foreach ($servicesname as $val) {
        $id++;
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size: 16px;" id="itemservices<?php 
echo $id ?>">
        <span style="float:left;" ><?php echo $val[0]['servicename']; ?>
</span>
        <a  style="float:right;" onclick=" addSrvToCart('itemservices<?php 
echo $id ?>')" >
            &#8377<strong> <?php echo $val[0]['amount']; ?></strong>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="id_<?php echo 
$id; ?>"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

and the code for next div:

```
<fieldset class="col-md-4" >
<legend>Cart</legend>
<div style="list-style:none;" class="no-left-padding">
    <div class="col-md-12"  id="cart" >

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 no-right-padding pull-right"  style="background-
color:#f3f0f0; padding-top:6px; border:1px solid#ccc">
        Total: ₨&nbsp;<label class="" id="sumAmount">0</label>
    </div>
<button style="margin-top:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" 
onclick="bookNowAfterFilter()">Book Now</button>
</fieldset>
```

and the Script is

```
function addSrvToCart(elem){
var div=$('#' + elem);
div.hide();
$('#cart').append(div.html());
var total = parseInt(div.find('strong').html()) + 
parseInt($('#sumAmount').html());
$('#sumAmount').html(total);
}
```

So the thing is that i an successfully able to send data to the next div but can not move that div when press cross icon to its original place and that data is not in new div any help is appreciated 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1khjh.png)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look into your question, i think the `data` attribute is gone help you.

Like at this part of the code you can put the `$val[0]['amount']` into the `data` attribute.

```
&#8377<strong> <?php echo $val[0]['amount']; ?></strong>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="id_<?php echo $id; ?>"></span>
```

Here is what you should do.

```
&#8377<strong> <?php echo $val[0]['amount']; ?></strong>
<span data-amount="<?php echo $val[0]['amount']; ?>" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="id_<?php echo $id; ?>"></span>
```

Now on click, you can get that data attribute and then you can display it in anywhere you want. 
Here is the example of how to get the `data` attribute `on click`

```
$('body').on('click', '#your_plus_id', function(e) {
    var amount = $(this).data('amount');
    // Now You can use the amount variable 
});
```

Comment: can you please add js fiddle for it? @AbhinandanDutt so I can help through that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/coldblood02/2gn1tohg/ is the link but after the amount there is suppose to be a plus icon and when it will go the the cart and all the things should be in div and in cart the plus icon will change to the cross icon to remove that data and place in that div